# Jlabel cant display int

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

i am fairly new to java and i am trying to display multiplication table using JLabel. The user will input two integers. m will be the number of times the multiplication should show and n will be the times table. p = answer that should be displayed when m x n This is my code

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class TimesTable extends JFrame
{
     public TimesTable(int m, int n, int p)
     {
          setTitle("TimesTable");
          //Container contents = getContentsPane();
          //contents.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 3, 20, 10));          

          //for loop to calculate the times table
           for(int num = 1; num >= m; m++)
           {
                 multiplyAnswer = numOfMultiply * multiplyBy;
                 Container contents = getContentsPane();
                 contents.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 3, 20, 10)); 
                 contents.add(new JLabel(m));
                 contents.add(new JLabel("x"));
                 contents.add(new JLabel(n));
                 contents.add(new JLabel("="));
                 contents.add(new JLabel(p));
           }

          setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          pack();
      }

      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
           int m = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
           int n = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

          TimesTable theTimesTable = new TimesTable(m, n, p);
          theTimesTable.setVisible(true);  
      }
```

but i keep getting an error. What should i do?

Comment: See [How to instantiate JLabel in javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#JLabel%28java.lang.String%29). Also, I Like to use `String.valueOf(n)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert your int to string because the label constructor that you are looking for wants a string. There are multiple ways of doing that. For example, you can use [Integer.toString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString%28%29):

`contents.add(new JLabel(Integer.toString(m)));`

Alternatively, you can convert it implicitly by concatenating it with an empty string, as the other answers suggest, i.e.:

`contents.add(new JLabel("" + m));`

Comment: thank you for your help. I now get an error that says " cannot find symbolTimesTable the TimesTable = new TimesTable(numOfMultiply, multiplyBy, multiplyAnswer)" symbol: variable multiplyAnswer location: class TimesTable

Answer (score 0):

```
contents.add(new JLabel(""+m));
```

Comment: thank you for your help. I now get an error that says " cannot find symbolTimesTable the TimesTable = new TimesTable(numOfMultiply, multiplyBy, multiplyAnswer)" symbol: variable multiplyAnswer location: class TimesTable –

Comment: You may not have defined the variable 'multiplyAnswer', where ever you are using it. Add a line int multiplyAnswer = <value> before accessing it...

Comment: sorry, the error was cannot find symbolTimesTable the TimesTable = new TimesTable(m, n, p)" symbol: variable p location: class TimesTable i changed the variable names..but now when i changed it back to m, n, p..i still get the same error

Comment: You have to define p exactly the way you are defining m and n

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
             contents.add(new JLabel(m+""));
             contents.add(new JLabel("x"));
             contents.add(new JLabel(n+""));
             contents.add(new JLabel("="));
             contents.add(new JLabel(p+""));
```

Comment: thank you for your help. I now get an error that says " cannot find symbolTimesTable the TimesTable = new TimesTable(numOfMultiply, multiplyBy, multiplyAnswer)" symbol: variable multiplyAnswer location: class TimesTable –

Comment: where you declare these three variable **multiplyAnswer, numOfMultiply, multiplyBy**

Comment: sorry, the error was cannot find symbolTimesTable the TimesTable = new TimesTable(m, n, p)" symbol: variable p location: class TimesTable. i changed the variable names..but now when i changed it back to m, n, p..i still get the same error